# Elasticsearch partial update not happening while using updateBuilder

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I have the following document in elastic search:

```
   {
      "postDate": "2016-03-09T11:57:37+0530",
      "message": "trying out Elasticsearch",
      "user": "ankita",
      "tags": [
        "testing"
      ]
    }
```

And i am trying to update it using jestHttpClient with following code:

```
 private static void updateDocument(JestClient client, String id) {


    String script = "{\n" +
            "    \"script\" : \"ctx._source.tags += tag\",\n" +
            "    \"params\" : {\n" +
            "        \"tag\" : \"blue\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}";
    //String script ="{ \"script\" : \"ctx._source.newfield = \"something\"\"}";
    try {
        Update update=new Update.Builder(script).index("article").type("type").id(id).build();
        client.execute(update);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But it is not updating the document , not sure what is wrong here,

Is there a way where we can partially update a document in elasticsearch?

Comment: Did you make sure that you have [enabled dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file?

Comment: i have downloaded elasticsearch using brew and i am new to MAC so can you help me find where i can locate elasticsearch.yml file.

Comment: Using brew, ES has been installed in `/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch`, and the file you're looking for should be at `/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/2.2.0/config/elasticsearch.yml`

Comment: got it what should i add for updating ?

Comment: According to the link I shared, you should add `script.inline: true`at the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks @Val its working now :) Also you should add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have [enabled dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file.

Since you have installed ES using brew, you can normally find that configuration file at `/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/2.2.0/config/elasticsearch.yml`

Simply append the following line to your file and restart ES:

```
script.inline: true
```

Your update script should work after that.

Comment: i got a problem after enabling inline it is executing from rest but not from jest api not sure why?

Comment: no it is not throwing any error just not updating the doc.

Comment: Hmmm, does a [simple search](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/tree/master/jest#searching-documents) or a [simple get](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/tree/master/jest#getting-documents) via Jest work?